# Extract String from Formatted Message

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, material-table, react-intl

I am trying to extract the string part from `FormattedMessage` so I can access it and export it using CSV.
Here is my `FormattedMessage` code (`IntlMessages.js`):

```
import React from 'react';
import {FormattedMessage, injectIntl} from 'react-intl';

const InjectMassage = props => <FormattedMessage {...props} />;

export default injectIntl(InjectMassage, {
  withRef: false
});
```

For displaying data, I use

```
<IntlMessage id="" />
```

where `IntlMessage` is coming from the import statement of the code of `FormattedMessage`.

```
import IntlMessage from ./"IntlMessages.js";
```

I am getting the string on the basis of id that is stored in a json file.

I want to just extract the string from `IntlMessage` so that I can manipulate and export as CSV as right now it is coming as `[object Object]`.
I am using material Table for displaying of data and it is like:

```
title: <IntlMessage id="" />
```

I am new to this react-intl and was not able to make progress so it would help me if someone can guide me in this.

EDIT:
I am using material-table and I want to download csv, but right now I am getting as headers as `[object Object]` because of `IntlMessages` only.
I want to return a string to title so that when I download, the string appears instead of `[object Object]`.

I have tried `<IntlProvider textComponent={React.Fragment}>` also but that is also not working.

Comment: Show me your current way of extracting the string as I'm not quite understand what you mean.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 4):

Use useIntl react hook:

```
import {useIntl} from 'react-intl';
const intl = useIntl();
const translatedMessage = intl.formatMessage({id: 'messageID'}),
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a class component you can use [`injectIntl`](https://formatjs.io/docs/react-intl/api#injectintl-hoc) HOC to provide the `intl` object to the props, then use `intl.formatMessage({...})` to get a title in string. The code in your question doesn't work because it uses `FormattedMessage` which is an react component (object):

```
const Content = injectIntl(MaterialTableContainer);
```

And inside the component that returns the `MaterialTable`:

```
<MaterialTable
  columns={[
    {
      title: this.props.intl.formatMessage({
        id: "titleId",
        defaultMessage: "Title"
      }),
      field: "name"
    },
```

### [Live Demo](https://x4nyg.csb.app/) ([Source Code](https://codesandbox.io/s/69643018-react-extract-string-from-formatted-message-x4nyg?file=/src/App.js))

Answer (score 1):

Use react-intl hook called useIntl
Then use its method formatMessge

Eg

> ```
> Import {useIntl} from 'react-intl'
>
> //Hook
> const intl = useIntl()
> //Usage
> intl.formatMessage(message)
> ```